# Rounded Corners + background Color Dynamic setting for Android button?

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

I would like to give below settings for Button in my application. You can think it as some theme changing for buttons.

**Style** Rounded or Normal

**Color** Red or yellow or blue or any Color code

I know with Shape defined in XML, I can achieve Rounded Corners. With `setBackgroundColor`, I can set any Color as background.

**problem**

Both   `setBackgroundColor`, `setBackground` are overriding one another based on the order i call them. So I can't achieve both effects on the same button. How can I achieve these two effects simultaneously. How can I get below multiple buttons from single Button class. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Well I did it with `GradientDrawable`

```
    int color = Color.rgb(255,0,0); //red for example
    int radius = 5; //radius will be 5px
    int strokeWidth = 2;

    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
    gradientDrawable.setColor(color);
    gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
    gradientDrawable.setStroke(strokeWidth, color);
    button.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when trying to have a rounded background on my LinearLayout and also be able to set the color dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

You can set both shape and background color of a button in a drawable resource and assign it as `android:background` in XML or `setBackgroundDrawable()` in code.

Below is an example of such a button:

**/res/drawable/button.xml**

This file is to set rounded shape and background color

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#0000ff" />
    </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**/res/color/button.xml**

(This file is to set text color)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0000ff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#0000ff" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#0000ff" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />

</selector>
```

Then you can initialize the button in your layout as:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/button"
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>
```

The button wil look as below (in default and pressed states from top to bottom):

[image]

Comment: I would like to achieve this dynamically, means some methods to change button style and color on the fly. Without defining multiple xml shapes for each color.

Comment: But you still need either to create shapes in code, or define them in xml files and apply. you're not picking the Drawable from nowhere